# OperationalError at /register/ no such table: CustomUser

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, sqlite3-python

```
models.py
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    adharcard = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CustomUser'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

```
views.py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.views import View
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import CustomUser



def home(request):
    return render(request, 'app/login.html')


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        adharcard = request.POST.get('adharcard')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        age = request.POST.get('age')
        hashed_password = make_password(password)

        user = CustomUser.objects.create(
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            email=email,
            password=hashed_password,
            address=address,
            adharcard=adharcard,
            phone=phone,
            age=age
        )
        user.save()
        return redirect('app/login.html')
    return render(request, 'app/register.html')


class LoginView(View):
    """
    Login view for the user.

    Returns:
        Response: indicating the result of the login attempt.
            - If successful, redirects to the dashboard.
            - If the user is not found, renders the login page with an error message.
            - If the password is incorrect, renders the login page with an error message.
    """

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'app/login.html')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app/dashboard.html'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'app/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid email or password'})

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    user_first_name = request.user.first_name
    return render(request, 'app/dashboard.html', {'user_first_name': user_first_name})
```

Error:

OperationalError at /register/ no such table: CustomUser  The above exception (no such table: CustomUser) was the direct cause of the following exception: D:\Platevisionx\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 55, in inner                 response = get_response(request)                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ … Local vars D:\Platevisionx\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 197, in _get_response                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ … Local vars D:\Platevisionx\platevision\app\views.py, line 28, in register         user = CustomUser.objects.create(                     … Local vars

I cant Solve the error I have ran python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate but it is not working for me.
Please anyone tell me the problem I an using sqlite3 in Django

Comment: is your app in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes its installed

Comment: did you run makemigrations and migrate commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `db_table = 'custom_user'` and again run migration. Try this method.

Answer (score 0):

**Problems :-**

1 )

You are trying to use custom password field. But you use django built-in authentication backend.
Like below.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)


login(request, user)
```

Above `login` and `authenticate` functions are built-in methods of django built-in authentication system. They doesn't use your password field in `models.py`.

2 )

Potential migration problems.

**Answers :-**

1 )

1)
I suggest you to use django built-in auth system.
Django already include built-in auth system, which you can customise for your needs.

2)
Write a custom authentication backend. It's not very hard to make a custom authentication backend.
It's the only way to make this work, if you want to keep using custom password fields in models.

Examples :-

[guide 1](https://reintech.io/blog/writing-custom-authentication-backend-django)

[guide 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/)

[guide 3](https://dev.to/amoabakelvin/creating-a-custom-authentication-backend-in-django-17bl)

2 )

Delete old migrations.
Then run makemigrations and migrate.